# Haskell - How do I iterate and compare?

Tags: list, haskell, iteration

I have an issue. I am currently learning Haskell, and trying to build a dungeon game.

Currently I am trying to implement a movement function for the player. Before moving to a new position,I must check if the player's new position will collide with the position of an object on the map of the game.

The code I have in my head (in Java/C) is fairly simple, yet I cannot think how it would cross over to Haskell. I'm pretty sure there's an alternative approach using Haskell code but this is the rough idea (Java/C):-

Let's assume the player object has x and y coordinates.
Let's also assume we store a list of other objects that the player may collide with in an array (this would be stored in a list for Haskell, I assume). Also, lets assume each object has an x and y co-ordinate.
The Boolean function returns `true` if a collision will occur, or `false` if not.

```
   Boolean detectCollision(Player p, Object[] o)
   {
       for(int i=0; i < o.length; i++){
           if(p.x==o[i].x && p.y==o[i].y){
               return true;
           }
       } return false; 
   }
```

If someone could help me figure this out I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Operations that would use iteration in an imperative language like C/Java is most often done using recursion in Haskell, either by explicitly in a function or else using existing capabilities like fold, map, or reduce

Answer (score 7):

Even if this were Java/C, I would recommend that you write a function that detects if a player and a single object would collide, so let's do that here:

```
collidesWith :: Player -> Object -> Bool
collidesWith player object =
    playerX player == objectX object && playerY player == objectY object
```

This is a little wordy, you can shorten this using the `lens` library to actually make it look like

```
collidesWith player object
    = player^.x == object^.x && player^.y == object^.y
```

But this is outside the scope of this question, just know that it's fully possible in Haskell.

For "looping" over a list in Haskell you can use recursion

```
detectCollision player [] = False  -- No objects, no collisions
detectCollision player (o:objects)
    = player `collidesWith` o || detectCollision player objects
```

Since Haskell is lazy, the first time `` player `collidesWith` o `` evaluates to `True` it will stop checking.  But this actually already exists as a standard built in function named `any`:

```
any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
```

And can be used as

```
detectCollision player objects = any (collidesWith player) objects
```

Haskell even lets you drop the `objects` argument through eta reduction, so it can be written simply as

```
detectCollision :: Player -> [Object] -> Bool
detectCollision player = any (collidesWith player)
```

And that's it!

Note: This is assuming that `Player` and `Object` are defined as

```
data Player = Player
    { playerX :: Int
    , playerY :: Int
    } deriving (Eq, Show)

data Object = Object
    { objectX :: Int
    , objectY :: Int
    } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Comment: As an aside that is a bit beyond the scope of the question, I like to represent positions using [`Point`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.20.2/docs/Linear-Affine.html) from the linear package. Then you can compare `player^.position == object^.position` and supply an `R2` instance for each that "delegates" so you can also say `player^._x` and `object^._y`.

Comment: It might be worth, pointing that Haskell is lazzy, therefore `any` *breaks* at the first collision.

Comment: @mb14 Edited to include that note